# Setup script with one module

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, setup.py

I use setuptools for creating the module installation script.
In [manual](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) of the setuptools module is presented the example of the project [directory structure](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#directory-structure). In this case an import of module `useful_1` will be look like: `from an_example_pypi_project import useful_1`.
So directive `packages` in `setup.py` [file](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#setting-up-setup-py) must also include package `an_example_pypi_project`.

What if I want use the `useful_1` module without any wrappers and import this module with simple instruction: `import useful_1`? How will look my `setup.py` file?

---

For example [this is](https://github.com/uzumaxy/pyvalid/blob/master/setup.py) a source code of my `setup.py` file. How you can see, I want include only 'pyvalid.py' file and I expect for a next import structure: `from pyvalid import accepts, returns`, where `accepts` and `returns` are classes in module `pyvalid`.

In directive `packages` of my setup script I put next value: `['.']`. This solution can solve my problem, but just partially, because I had obtained new troubles.

1. On the installation I encounter with this warning:

   WARNING: '.' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
2. Installation script also include some unnecessary files:

   `/fakepath/site-packages/pyvalid-0.0.2-py3.4.egg-info`
   `/fakepath/site-packages/pyvalid.py`
   `/fakepath/site-packages/__init__.py` -- unnecessary
   `/fakepath/site-packages/setup.py` -- unnecessary
   `/fakepath/site-packages/test.py` -- unnecessary

---

**Question**: how I can create `setup.py` script with one module? Thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the one solution of my problem. I can create package named "pyvalid" and in the file `__init__.py` define objects for an import.

In my case, directive `packages` in `setup.py` file must look like: `packages=["pyvalid"]`.

This way will allow me to create installation script for project with following import structure: `from pyvalid import some_object`.